How to handle large configurable products
I have few configurable products with huge number of variations. They have almost 5k children simple products assigned to them on average.
While loading the files both on admin and frontend, it takes long time. Any kind of save / update operations are same way consumes a lot of time. I had to increase memory limit and time out in my server configuration to prevent errors.
Is there any way to optimize the handling the large configurable products? Because theoretically Magento doesn't have any limit of children products for a single configurable product.
If a configurable product with 5000 associated products makes the system slow, a product with more than 20k or 30k child products would crash the system.
EDIT:
Found an open issues related to this. I have already my indexers set to schedule.

For large configurable products I recommend you use Elgentos_LargeConfigProducts
https://github.com/elgentos/LargeConfigProducts

This extension is built to work around the problems Magento 2 is
causing when using configurable products with extremely large amounts
of simple products associated to it. Magento 2 can handle up to around
3000 associated simple products pretty well. Above that, it becomes
extremely slow and sometimes unusable (such as webserver timeouts).

I have been using this module for many years in Production and it works extremely efficiently. Large configurable products load very quickly.
I can confirm the module is compatible with Magento 2.4.X

Was this out of the box compatible with Magento 2.4.X or you had to do any modifications on it ? They mention only compatibility of 2.3.X on their page.

I have been contributing to this project. I haven't had to update it since 2.3.x because I haven't found any issues with 2.4.x. Of course you should test it yourself before using it in production.

The module works great with Magento 2.4.7 p-2. One query I had regarding the process. After creating or modifying a large configurable product, the consumer runner should automatically generate / regenerate the pre-warming data using cron  ? Or do I have to run the consumer runner manually ?

If your messaging is working correctly in Magento the module will create a prewarm message which should be run by the consumer automatically when you save a parent or child product in admin.

Thank you, it works
